# Android light sensor via RxJava - optimizations

Tags: android, rx-java, android-sensors, light

I've implemented the light sensor using RxJava implementation. I receive `lux` values correctly, but the variation is very high. 
For example, even when the device moves very little, the values change and are emitted via the sensor listener.

```
@NonNull
@Override
Observable<Boolean> createObservable(@NonNull Context context) {
    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(
            Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    List<Sensor> sensorList = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
    if (null == sensorList || sensorList.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported Sensor: Device has no light sensor");
    }

    return SensorEventObservableFactory
            .createSensorEventObservable(sensorList.get(0), sensorManager,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)
            // Ambient light level in SI lux units
            .map(sensorEvent -> sensorEvent.values[0])
            // Make sure the lux value is valid
            .filter(lx -> !(null == lx || lx < 0))
            // Detect if light or dark environment
            .map(lx -> {
                Timber.d("new LX value = %s", lx);
                // Over 15 lx means it is a light environment
                // Bellow 15 lx means it is a dark environment
                return lx > 15f;
            })
            .distinctUntilChanged();
}
```

How can I avoid this issue? I've been thinking I can add an delay between events, but this could get me in situations where the detection is not very fast and the risk is high to get stuck in an ambient mode. I've been struggling with this for a few hours and I'm out of ideas on how to efficiently detect ambient light.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unrelated to Rx per se, but you could get a N-sized batch of measurements, average them and only then act based on the data

Comment: I tried this, by using `buffer()` method, but I was getting invalid data as only the last value was relevant.
I've added a little optimization to avoid emitting many results which weren't of interest.

Comment: What Edson Menegatti described(moving average) seems to be a good option to lower variance of results.

Look into that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811745/how-to-calculate-moving-average-in-rxjava
It is shown as a final operation(in subscriber but you can with some work convert it to an operator.

Comment: Let's say I receive an batch of 3 values: `150, 149, 5`. If the lux is bellow 15 it means it is very dark (i'm interested in dark environments). 
If I do the average, I will get `101` lux units as the result. Thus, I will not correctly detect the dark environment.
If this is not the approach you recommend, please post an detailed answer. 
Thank you.